# One SQL query instead of three sql queries

Tags: mysql

My server database took too long to run two sql queries by separate thread. I'm doing so in PHP:

```
$First=mysql_query("SELECT `ID`,`Country` FROM `Users` WHERE `IP`='".$ip."'",$connection);

 $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($First);
 $id=$row['ID']; 
 $ucountry=$row['Country']; 

$opt=mysql_query("SELECT Size,Paper,Zip FROM Tools WHERE (Users LIKE '%".$id."%') OR (Users LIKE '".$id."%') OR (Users LIKE '%".$id."') OR (Users LIKE '".$id."') OR (Users LIKE 'All users') OR (Country LIKE '".$ucountry."') OR (Country LIKE 'All countries')",$connection);
```

How to do all this stuff in mysql in just one query?

I tried this:

```
SELECT  (SELECT `ID` FROM `Users` WHERE `IP`='xx.xx.xx.xx'  ) AS UID, (SELECT `Country` FROM  `Users` WHERE `IP`='xx.xx.xx.xx'  ) AS UCountry, (SELECT Size,Paper,Zip FROM Tools WHERE (Users LIKE CONCAT('%#',UID,'#%')) OR (Users LIKE CONCAT('#',UID,'#%')) OR (Users LIKE CONCAT('%#',UID,'#')) OR (Users LIKE CONCAT('#',UID,'#')) OR (Users LIKE 'All users') OR (Country LIKE UCountry) OR (Country LIKE 'All countries'))
```

Comment: By making it one query, you will not necessarily make it faster. In fact, it often becomes slower.

Comment: Why `(Users LIKE '%".$id."%') OR (Users LIKE '".$id."%') OR (Users LIKE '%".$id."') OR (Users LIKE '".$id."') OR (Users LIKE 'All users')`?

Comment: Also why `LIKE` for every comparison? `=` is probably faster.

Comment: I need to use LIKE because Users can have diffrent format.. and LIKE do that I need. just = cannot do what is needed.

Comment: I think you're first problem is that your data isn't in a good format. You should really try to standardize your IDs so you can do `WHERE id = $id`. I'm guessing you have some sort of comma-seperated list instead of multiple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to be sure that only the first row is used on your select from users to be replicated in the SQL you'll need to JOIN to an inline query

```
SELECT t.SIZE, 
       t.paper, 
       t.zip 
FROM   tools t 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT `id`, 
                          `country` 
                   FROM   `users` 
                   WHERE  `ip` = ? 
                   LIMIT  1) u 
       ON t.Users  like CONCAT('%',u.id '%')
           OR t.user LIKE 'All users'
           OR Country LIKE  CONCAT('%',u.country '%') 
           OR Country LIKE 'All countries'
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need LIKE with wildcards.  Some of your LIKEs appear to be redundant, since you are matching with % on front and back already.

```
$query = "SELECT Users.ID
          ,Users.Country
          ,Tools.Users
          ,Tools.Country
          ,Tools.Size
          ,Tools.Paper
          ,Tools.Zip
FROM Tools
INNER JOIN Users
ON Users.IP = '$ip'
AND (
    Tools.Users LIKE CONCAT('%', Users.ID, '%')
    OR Tools.Users = 'All users'
    OR Tools.Country LIKE Users.Country
    OR Tools.Country = 'All countries'
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Size, t.Paper, t.Zip
FROM Tools AS t
INNER JOIN Users AS u 
  ON (Users LIKE CONCAT('%', u.ID, '%')) 
    OR (Users LIKE CONCAT(u.ID, '%'))
    OR (Users LIKE CONCAT('%', u.ID))
    OR (Users LIKE u.ID)
    OR (Users LIKE 'All users')
    OR (Country LIKE u.Country)
    OR (Country LIKE 'All countries')
WHERE ( u.IP = '$ip' )
```

Some of your LIKE criteria are superfluous since they are necessarily true because of the previous one.

Therefore, the previous query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT t.Size, t.Paper, t.Zip
FROM Tools AS t
INNER JOIN Users AS u 
  ON (Users LIKE CONCAT('%', u.ID, '%')) 
    OR (Users LIKE 'All users')
    OR (Country LIKE u.Country)
    OR (Country LIKE 'All countries')
WHERE ( u.IP = '$ip' )
```

Comment: If I would like to only insert a row, if the following SELECT returns a 0 or no rows.

Something like:

**IF ( SELECT IS 0) THEN INSERT()**

how can I do this in MYSQL ?

I just want to do one query instead of this two queries:

$r=mysql_query("SELECT ID,Country FROM Users WHERE IP='".$ip."'",$connection);

if(!$r || mysql_num_rows($r) <= 0)

$ir=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (IP,Country) VALUES ('".$ip."','".$country."')",$connection);